# Incorrect "warning" Vetur - Vue.js - VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

My VSCode (Vetur) is displaying this warning, however the imported component is being used in the template.

Warning in import **:**

[image]

Component used **:**

[image]

Another issue is that the summaries are appearing in duplicate, as well as the CSS color thumbnails. I have already uninstalled some extensions and reviewed the settings but I couldn't find the option that causes this.

Color duplicate **:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vetur is deprecated and doesn't actually support `<script setup>`. The [Vue docs officially recommend Volar](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#ide-support).

Uninstall Vetur, and use [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) instead.

Comment: This solved both problems. Thank you!